# Instantiate a class in exported DLL function using getProcAddress

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, dll

I have following .h code for DLL and using getProcAddress to consume DLL in another code.

```
// MathFuncsDll.h

#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace MathFuncs
{
    // This class is exported from the MathFuncsDll.dll
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        int x = 10;
        MyMathFuncs();

           // Returns a + b + x
           MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b); 

    };
}
```

And corresponding .cpp code is

```
// MathFuncsDll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application. 
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    MyMathFuncs ::MyMathFuncs()
    {
            x = 10;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b + x;
    }

}
```

The function Add is exported and it adds a and b along with initial value of x = 10.

I have created a DLL file of same and calling the functions using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

The code works fine when I do not use constructor and directly add 10 i.e a + b + 10. But it fails when I do a + b + x, and basically constructor is not called.

How to instantiate such object using GetProcAddress so that when I load DLL and call function I get instantiated object method.

Answer (score 4):

Calling the constructor is **not** automatic.  This is normally taken care of by the C++ compiler when you use `operator new` but that is no longer being done.  You will have to use GetProcAddress() to get the constructor address and invoke it.

And before you do that, you have to allocate memory for the object.  Whose address you pass to the constructor.  This is where it gets difficult, you have no idea how much memory to allocate.  It is guessable for a simple class like this one but optimizations applied by the C++ compiler when the class has virtual methods or implements multiple inheritance rapidly make this unpractical.

This is a big reason that interop with C++ is so difficult and poorly supported by other language runtimes.  The only *reliable* way to do it is to also export a class factory function, a simple function that uses the new operator to create the object and return the pointer.  There's now also a problem with destroying the object, you need some kind of memory manager that ensures that the correct implementation of `operator delete` is called as well.  Typically done by reference counting, like std::shared_ptr<>.

All and all, you'll be well on your way to re-inventing COM.

Comment: Agreed. But I am using DLL of c++ code. MyMathFuncs.h [pastebin.com/Q5P3e2wS] MyMathfuncs.cpp [pastebin.com/0HGBKzBe] test.cpp which uses DLL file created by previous code. [pastebin.com/GeNDvVGA]. test.cpp has no access to MyMathFuncs.h to instantiate class. It has DLL access. Only getProcAddress can give me access to Add function but can not instantiate class. What could be the possible way to do this gracefully.

Comment: Well, that was the point of the answer.  If you don't have "access" to the .h file then there's no way to guess how much memory you need to allocate to create the object.  I already explained the "graceful" way, add a class factory.

Comment: So it is important to have a function that will give object of class in return. Also I am not sure about giving direct call to constructor using function pointer as it can not return me any value. So I need to have class factory always in such case?

Comment: What if one do not implement class factory and I still want to consume gracefully?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark your class as exported to export all member functions including contructors:

```
class MATHFUNCSDLL_API MyMathFuncs {
...
};
```

After that you can use this class easially as it is:

```
MyMathFuncs funcs;
double r = funcs.Add(10.0, 10.0);
```

Comment: New code is : `class MATHFUNCSDLL_API  MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        int x = 10;
        MyMathFuncs();

           // Returns a + b + x
           double Add(double a, double b); 

    };` But no effect. Still returns garbage.

Comment: Yes that hold true if you instantiate a class. But I am trying to use it via DLL. getProcAddress just gives me a pointer to the function but does not give me a way to instantiate a class and use its object. Am I clear with the issue?

Comment: it would be good if you show your code. But anyway, you have to understand that all member functions (for example, Add) have one more parameter (it is pointer to MyMathFuncs data structure). So, if you want to call Add you have to pass as the first parameter pointer to MyMathFuncs object which holds the data (in your case x=10)

Comment: `#define CONVENTION __thiscall

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 string t = "MathFuncsDll.dll";
 HINSTANCE hMod = LoadLibrary(t.c_str());
 if(NULL == hMod){
  cout << "Load Library Failed\n";
  return 1;
 } else {
  typedef double (CONVENTION *funcp)(double, double);
  string func = "?Add2@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@QAENNN@Z";
  funcp temp_ptr = (funcp) GetProcAddress(hMod,func.c_str());
  if(temp_ptr == 0x00 || temp_ptr == NULL){
   cout << "Please verify function name.. It does not exist \n";
   return 1;
  }else {
   double temp = temp_ptr(1.0, 2.0);
   cout << temp;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: For you the correct way is to declare structure MyMathFuncs and export function double add(MyMathFuncs* object, double a, double b)

Comment: sorry for code in single line. It is not allowing to make multiple lines.

Comment: To make MyMathFuncs *Object, I need access to .h file and class. DLL file do not give that access to instantiate a class. Atleast I am not aware of it. So seeking for help.

Comment: As I said above your have to undestand low level background. I tried to explaid it here: http://pastebin.com/yKNvVLAW

Comment: If you have no access to data structure you can emit it: char bufferToHoldMyMathFuncs[sizeWhichEqualOrGreaterThanMyMathFuncsSize]; After that you have to put there data according to data member of your class.

Comment: Here seems to be some confusion. MathFuncsDll.cpp and MathFuncsDll.h files will form a DLL which is MathFuncsDll.dll. The code consuming DLL have only DLL file and **not H and CPP files**. Only way to access DLL functions in use getProcAddress function given by visual-c++. Which returns me a function pointer to Add function. So MyMathFunc Object; is not doable as code which is accessing DLL has no idea about .cpp and .h file only thing it knows is .DLL file.

Comment: MyMathFuncs.h [http://pastebin.com/Q5P3e2wS] MyMathfuncs.cpp [http://pastebin.com/0HGBKzBe] test.cpp which uses DLL file created by previous code. [http://pastebin.com/GeNDvVGA]. test.cpp has no access to MyMathFuncs.h to instantiate class. It has DLL access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disassembly the DLL you want to use. Then, extract information about the class you want to use from it.